# Why is Leak Canary not showing a notification when run with a debugger attached?

Tags: android, leakcanary

I installed Leak Canary as per the instructions in their GitHub repo but no notification is showing up when I run it with a debugger attached in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Leak Canary will do nothing on purpose as long as a Debugger is attached to the process, as can be seen [when debugging into the library's code](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/111609ecc2afacf48812fea95916ee2d0e742f2b/leakcanary-watcher/src/main/java/com/squareup/leakcanary/RefWatcher.java#L106).

Apparently, the debugger may cause false memory leak reports. Thus, the only way to get Leak Canary notifications is to run it without the debugger attached (but remember that you must run the debug APK!).